# truncate and pad using format specification mini language

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm currently writing code which pads a string with spaces, using Python's [format specification mini language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
print('''{user:<10}, you're welcome!'''.format(user='John Doe'))
```

The output is:

```
John Doe  , you're welcome!
```

However, if user's name is something like 'Joooooooooooohn Doe', I'd like to output:

```
Jooooooooo, you're welcome!
```

Is there a way to perform truncation AND padding using the format specification mini language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

> For non-number types [precision]
>   indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters
>   will be used from the field content. The precision is not allowed for
>   integer values.

Precision is introduced by a period

> `format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]`

So the correct format string is `{user:<10.10}`.

```
>>> '{0:<10.10}'.format('1234567')
'1234567   '

>>> '{0:<10.10}'.format('123456789034')
'1234567890'
```