# formate a string and truncate from right

Tags: python

trying to find a way to format a string in logger format that will show last module name without the long path

i found this solution that truncates with specific width but to the left

[truncate and pad using format specification mini language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302815/truncate-and-pad-using-format-specification-mini-language/14302858#14302858)

using the same example, expected behavior:

```
>>> '{0:<w.p}'.format('path.not.long.module')
'.not.long.module  '

>>> '{0:<w.p}'.format('path.other.very.long.module')
'.very.long.module '

>>> '{0:<w.p}'.format('short.module')
'short.module      '
```

current json format - i am trying to edit the path in name field:

```
"format": "{levelname:8s}; {asctime:s}; {name:<15s} {lineno:4d}; {message:s}"
```

Expected output:

```
DEBUG; 09:15:00; truncated.path.name    1111; Log message with logger
```

Comment: Can you edit to show what your expected output is for the string you're trying to format?

Comment: edited expected behavior, but the main issue is using width and precision to truncate from right not left...

Comment: I meant the expected output for your json